# I want a Idea in how to create a program that reads the screen of windows and transform all visual details to sounds

Tags: python

I mean, I will implement the code, but I'm not sure how to create a problem using python to read the screen and for instance reproduce hundreds or thousands sounds at the same time or in secuence of less than 10 miliseconds.

The idea is to hear images, meaning if I were blind I can hear the screen images.
I thougth about to create mini-horns, meaning for each pixel creating one horn and create a unique frecuenci for the main colors, but yeah, I need nanotecnology to do that.

any one have heard about any program to translate images into sounds. or how to make blind people be able to use a computers but with sounds. I know the idea is weird or insane but yeah I started to program with this idea in mind. but not sure yet how to do this. any idea or critics are welcome.

I did code using python to assign 1 beep sound with a unique frecuency to all asscii, but after each beep there was a pause even if in the code this was not coded , there is a sound pause to change into another . but I left the idea cause I need to beable to reproduce at least like 10 different waves of sounds at the same time which are the pixels,

to resume, I need a program that if my resolution is 1000 x 500, the program can reproduce this 500000  differents waves in less than 1 second,. my idea looks imposible and insane but yeah, it's the reason why I started to learn code, so I think it's time to get help.

Comment: *clarifications, sooner or later I'll be able to figure this out, but sooner is better, and just to clarify, the idea is not to read the screen to translate the screen text into words but is to translate all pixels like they are to raw sounds , I will figure it out , but I need to check if someone else has heard about something similar or know a book or something I can investigate.

Comment: While this is a really interesting concept, open-ended questions like these aren't a good fit for StackOverflow. If you start building your project and encounter a *specific* difficulty with your code, that will get much better results.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead, lets say you take a image and a sound, for example a bird on a branch and the sound will be tweeting and windrushing. Then if you have a couple thousands of those examples as a pair of training data and target, after your machine learning project is finished. You can just represent a picture and have it produce noise. I haven't had a look at Ml in over a year and a bit but might be a interesting experiment if its just a hobby

Comment: That's actually a really cool idea, and sounds a lot more doable than trying to actually *transcribe* images into sound!